# Stack layout wont fit elements when large text is On

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make my app more compatible with accessibility features, and when a large text is enabled I cant fit two elements in a horizontally oriented stack. Any idea how I can fix this?

```
        StackLayout horisontalContainer = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };

        List<string> dataList = this.registerCountries();
        List<string> numberList = this.registerAreaCodes();
        List<string> pickerData = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var data in dataList)
        {
            pickerData.Add(data + " +" + numberList[i]);
            i++;
        }

        countryCode = new Picker { Title = "Country code" };
        countryCode.ItemsSource = pickerData;
        countryCode.IsEnabled = true;
        countryCode.SelectedIndex = 0;
        countryCode.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var tempValue = countryCode.Items[countryCode.SelectedIndex];
            string[] words = tempValue.Split('+');
            pickerSelection = words[words.Length-1];
        };

        phoneNbrEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = Localization.MobileNumber,
            FontSize = 18,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White.ToFormsColor(),
            TextColor = Color.Black.ToFormsColor(),
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Telephone,
        };
```

#if **IOS**
phoneNbrEntry.WidthRequest = UIKit.UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width/2-20;
#endif

#if **ANDROID**
phoneNbrEntry.WidthRequest = CrossScreen.Current.Size.Width/2-20;
#endif

```
        horisontalContainer.Children.Add(countryCode);
        horisontalContainer.Children.Add(phoneNbrEntry);
```

Images:
[image: Enlarged text]
[image: Normal]

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT yes it does. I was hoping for a stack solution, but I did change it to grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StackLayout** will not fit the size with its child elements .  In your case it would be better to  use **Grid** instead of  **Stacklayout** so that we could set the width of the **Picker** and **Label** as a relative value .

```
    Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

            Padding = new Thickness(10,0),

            RowDefinitions =
            {
              
              new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(60) },
               
            },

            ColumnDefinitions =
            {

              // the width of picker and label will fill half of the screen
              new ColumnDefinition{Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
              new ColumnDefinition{Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
            }
        };

        var countryCode = new Picker { Title = "Country code" };
        //countryCode.ItemsSource = pickerData;
        countryCode.IsEnabled = true;
        countryCode.TitleColor = Color.Red;
        countryCode.SelectedIndex = 0;

        var phoneNbrEntry = new Entry
        {
            Placeholder = "11111111",
            FontSize = 38,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Telephone,
        };

        grid.Children.Add(countryCode,0,0);
        grid.Children.Add(phoneNbrEntry,1, 0);


        
        Content = grid;

    }
```

**[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1v8y.png)**